# Who is the (new) CMO on the Excalibur?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-new-frontier

I know none of the *Star Trek: New Frontier* series by Peter David is 'canon' (televised) but I've just started reading the books and I know that in one of them Dr Selar

> dies.

I've looked at the Excalibur crew but cannot find who

> replaces her as Chief Medical Officer

Comment: Could you please state which book you read that in, so those of us who are behind on the series don't get spoiled? Pretty sure I haven't read that particular spoiler and I'm like 8 books in or so.

Comment: Hi, I've not yet read all the New Frontier novels myself, but her death is in the Memory Beta page about her on Google. Apparently her and Burgoyne have a son, Xyon, who ages rapidly and she becomes obsessed with trying to reverse this, leading to her going mad and eventually leading to her death. This is apparently in the novel 'Treason' which I have, but haven't read yet.

Comment: Umm, dude, could you stop making your question worse by posting more spoilers?